Rank deficiency in a linear mixed model
I have a linear mixed model with 4 fixed factors and 1 random factor: V ~ A + B + C + D + (1|E). I want to compare this model with a model with an additional interaction term.
When I add an interaction term to this model (e.g. V ~ A + B + C + D + C:D + (1|E)), I get a rank deficiency error message in R: "fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 1 column / coefficient".
Why do I get this error message?
If I replace C:D with A:D, I do not get this error message.

Would it be relevant to check table(C,D,A) and table(C,D,B)?
